# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `categorie

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `categories` (`category_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fruits, 2022-08-08 10:46:52, 2022-08-08 10:46:52))**

How to solve that ??

The name of my controller is "CategorieController".This is my store function called sauvercategorie in CategorieController.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categorie;


class CategorieController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function ajoutercategorie(){
        return view('admin.ajoutercategorie');
    }

    public function sauvercategorie(Request $request){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required | max:255',
        ]);

        $categorie = Categorie::create($validatedData);


        return redirect('/ajoutercategorie')->with('status', 'La catégorie'
        .$categorie->category_name.'a été ajoutée avec succès');
```

My entire blade file.

```
@extends('layouts.appadmin')

@section('title')
    Ajouter une catégorie
@endsection

@section('contenu')


    <div class="row grid-margin">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Ajouter une catégorie</h4>

                  @if (Session::has('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{Session::get('status')}}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="post" action="{{ route('categories.sauvercategorie') }}">
                      @csrf
                    <fieldset>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cemail">Nom de la catégorie</label>
                        <input id="cemail" class="form-control" type="text" name="category_name" >
                      </div>

                      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Ajouter">

                    </fieldset>

                    </form>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


@endsection

@section('scripts')
    {{--<script src="Administrateur/js/form-validation.js"></script>
    <script src="Administrateur/js/bt-maxLength.js"></script>--}}
@endsection
```

the name of model is Categorie. This is my model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categorie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
        protected $fillable = ['category_name'];
}
```

my table name is "categories". This is my table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('categorie_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

**Need helps to solve that, thanks.**

Comment: Is the column named `categorie_name` or `category_name`?

Answer (score 0):

your field name in migration and model is different.

Change your model from:

```
protected $fillable = ['category_name'];
```

into :

```
protected $fillable = ['categorie_name'];
```

Comment: Yes I did that and I think it gives me this as an error: **Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**  While in my blade file, this is the POST method I used.  Here is my route: `Route::get('/ajoutercategorie', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@ajoutercategorie');
Route::post('/sauvercategorie', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@sauvercategorie')->name('categories.sauvercategorie');
Route::get('/categorie', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@categorie');` How to do ?

Comment: if u use create method in controller. your route should be Route::post('url'), or if you only want to get the data, you can use Route::get('url'). Furthermore you can check this link to give you some explanation about Route https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#available-router-methods

Comment: Thanks. It work well already. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is occuring error because you have different column name in your Categorie model.

Change this,

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('categorie_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

to this,

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and run the command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```